# APP_INITIALIZER with SSR problem in Angular 17

Tags: angular, angular-universal

guys. I encountered a problem when I try to migrate to SSR in Angular 17. My app is client only in Angular 16.
I have a service named CiyuanEnvironmentService and another service named LiveService.
The LiveService access the CiyuanEnvironmentService environment property which is loaded with HttpClient asynchronously, and I make the method as factory method or APP_INITIALIZER.
In non-SSR, it will finished before the LiveService access it. But in SSR, it seems that it will access to it before it's ready.
How can I solve it? Or is there another one for SSR? Thank you.

```js
    CiyuanEnvironmentService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (ciyuanEnvironmentService: CiyuanEnvironmentService) => () => ciyuanEnvironmentService.loadEnvironment(),
      deps: [CiyuanEnvironmentService],
      multi: true
    }
```

It seem that I should use this with SSR.

```js
  loadEnvironment() {
    let ret = this.httpClient.get<CiyuanEnvironment>(environment.ciyuanEnvironmentFile)
    ret.subscribe(config => {
      this.environment = config;
    });
    return ret;
  }
```

Previously, this is working in client only app.

```js
  loadEnvironment() {
    return this.httpClient.get<CiyuanEnvironment>(environment.ciyuanEnvironmentFile).subscribe(config => {
      this.environment = config;
    });
  }
```

Is this intended?

Comment: Hi @Seto, did you solved your problem? I think I have the same :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't return a subscribtion but a Promise. Try this:

```
loadEnvironment() {
    return firstValueFrom(this.httpClient.get<CiyuanEnvironment>(environment.ciyuanEnvironmentFile))
    .pipe(tap(config => this.environment = config))
  }
```